# Simple C++ Instant messenger

Tags: c++, instant

I want to make a very simple c++ instant messenger for lan networks and internet (direct IP connect). I know little about sockets. I searched the internet, but nothing really helped. I would someone to suggest a howto/tutorial/guide. I just want to send and receive messages (in a console window, I'll create the gui later). I want it to be for both Linux and Windows. Thanks in advance!

Comment: None of the answers really helped. Thanks though. I tried Boost.Asio (it didn't compile), Qt (it works, but I do not know much about it) and the "codeproject.com" example but many problems occured. Can anybody suggest anything else?

Comment: what compiler/version did you use? which Boost release did you try?  what were some of the "many problems" you had with Qt?  will anything but a complete solution breastfed satisfy you?

Comment: @just somebody: I didn't say that I have problems with Qt, but with the codeproject example. I used the GNU compiler for boost, but people also confirmed that there are problems with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checkout [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). It's portable, and it's also got an example that implements a simple chat.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and post if I have any questions.

Comment: I cannot find where to download the libraries and the headers.

Comment: Download at http://www.boost.org/users/download/. You will have to do some reading to get this working though.

Comment: I get a linker error while trying to compile the example code in dev-c++:   [Linker error] undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume' 
Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: from my experience, examples (of any boost libraries i've tried) don't always compile.  try a different example file.  or which example it is.  or something.

Comment: It is the only chat client example. I tried linking many different libs, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3):

check out Boost.ASIO

Comment: duplicate of the above by space cowboy. his also provides a link.

Comment: @Jason - this one isn't the duplicate - it came first

Comment: It came first.. but now link no nothing :)

Answer (score 3):

There's some source code here for a C/S chat application that you could probably use to get started.

Mas.

[Example Code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/chat_client_server.aspx)

Comment: I tried that earlier, but there is a header file I couldn't find.

Comment: @MaSuGaNa - I was wrong, it was a similar project of the same author which used a header I couldn't find.
Is this only for windows, or I misunderstood?

Comment: The code looks easy enough to modify for cross platform use. If you want something already written I'd go with Boost.

Answer (score 2):

Use [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html), cross platform, under the link, straight forward example for client-server chat.